# Copy Selected items from AWS dyanmoDB table to another table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, data-migration, amazon-data-pipeline

I want to copy the data from one Amazon dynamodb table to another amazon dynamodb table(of same region)..

1]I have table called MUSIC which has 20 items
2] I have another table MUSIC_ST (with same schema as table MUSIC).
Now I want to migrate selectively 10 items from MUSIC dynamodb table To MUSIC_ST dynamodb table..

I went through AWS data-pipeline,Here first need to export the entire table to S3 then we need to import that file in S3 to dynamodb table through this data pipeline.. Which is not my project requirement.
 We need to migrate the selected data from one dynamoDB table to another DynamoDb table.

Please your solution will help me. And i appreciate it.
Thanks

Comment: What you are asking for is not an available feature with aws datapipeline. There are community utilities created by people to do the same. Building something custom using the aws sdk will not be bad idea either. If the data is huge is size, you may need to consider map reduce(emr) to build something of your own

Comment: @Shibashis: Can you please mention/suggest few community utilities who does this data migration as per my project requirement?.. That will be very helpful.. Thank you.

Comment: @Tedd did you get an answer or how did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you can't move data straight from one DynamoDB table in one account to another table in a different account without introducing S3 to stage such a move.

You need to export the data from the source table to S3.  You then need to set up a data pipeline job in the account where your destination table is and import the data from S3 into the destination table.  Make sure the data in the first account is accessible from the second account.  You can create or update a bucket policy to allow such access.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and suggestion.. Using AWS data pipeline is not my project requirement: I dont want to copy the entire table.. Only selected items of the table need to copied to other table.. Please let me know if you know any solution to this. Thanks

Comment: @Tedd even i have same requirement ? could you please tell me how to achieved  it ?